# Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.Version' after upgrade to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I've upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 in Canary channel and I cannot build my project anymore, this error is printed:

> Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.Version'. Possible causes
>   for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>     project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible
>   with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle
>   requested by the project. In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you
>   can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I already tried both of those solutions and also tried deleting all the `~/.gradle/caches` directory but the error persists.

Looking for similar error I've found the old version of Android Studio having this issues with the suggested solution to upgrade the android tools version.

I think I already have the last one:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
```

**EDIT (30 Oct 2017):**

Answers show that someone is having the issue while someone isn't.
As pointed out in the comments to this question this can be caused by a non compatible plugin, so I list the plugins used in my project here:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
//        maven {
//            url 'https://maven.google.com'
//        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.10"
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

The dexcount one is currently not used tough because of some incompatibilities with newer versions of Android plugin.

Comment: Yes you have the latest android gradle plugin but is not compatible with  the other plugins.Can you list other plugins of your project?

Comment: That could actually explain while I've the issue while others don't... Yes I can list other plugins, I'll edit my question.

Comment: It is from the `dexcount` plugin, we are working on it here: https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/pull/225.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same issue and what we have in common is the dexcount plugin. Disabling this issue until the two plugins are compatible. See [dexcount bug report](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/issues/234).

"updating to dexcount 0.8.2 fixes the issue"

Comment: you were right, i forgot to update this issue, I accepted your answer and added a link to the bug i created on dexcount.

Comment: fixed in dexcount 0.8.2

Comment: Combination of gradle-4.4 and dexcount 0.8.2 works for me in Android studio 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently going back to a previous version of the Android Tools plugin works:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

But the IDE ask me if I want to update to `3.1.0-alpha1` so I wander if this is a bug or if the issue lay somewhere else.

I just leave this solution here until someone else come up with another explanation.

Comment: I've the same issue. I'm going back to version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why your build is not working, but after a clean install of [Android Studio 3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html) and using this setting everything works fine compiling a large project which contains several libraries (and mixed with java, kotlin).

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = "3.1.0-alpha01"
        kotlin_version = "1.1.51"
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500"
        }
    }

}
```

and my app-based gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed my class path line in gradle (project : project name) and issue is gone.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'